# angular2 http delete

Tags: http, angular2-services, http-delete

I use http.delete for remove my data.

This code in my service [MyService]:

```
deleteData(id){
  let headers = new Headers(),authtoken = localStorage.getItem('token');
     headers.append("Authorization", 'Bearer' + authtoken);
     headers.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')
     headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json;')

    return this.http.delete('http://link/'+id, { headers: headers })
                  .map((resp:Response)=>resp.json())
                  .catch((error:any) =>{return Observable.throw(error);}); 
 }
```

This code in my component:

```
private delete(id):void{
         console.log(id); //show`s id
         this.myService.deleteData(id)
         .subscribe((data) => {console.log(data)});
}
```

Show`s error "caused by: A network error occurred".   My mistake was elsewhere. It is work.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in your code what i can see and you are not getting any error from server either. Try to call the same end point from postman and match the headers and check your Internet connection.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. My mistake was elsewhere. It is work.